# How to customize the log output for a job in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, supervisord

I see that Laravel uses the Monolog library to handle logs. I have the following handle method in the job:

**ApiUpdateItemJob.php:**

```
public function handle()
{
    $data = [
        'id' => $this->item_id,
        'data[status]' => $this->status,
    ];

    $response = ApiFacedeClient::exec('Item', 'update', $data);

    $result = json_decode($response->getBody());
}
```

In the worker's log (supervisor) I see the following:

```
[2019-12-17 02:13:13][40770367] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
[2019-12-17 05:11:53][40792760] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
[2019-12-17 05:11:54][40792761] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
[2019-12-17 05:11:54][40792760] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
[2019-12-17 05:11:54][40792762] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
```

What should I add to the job to see the following line:

> [2019-12-17 05:11:54][40792762] Processing item id #333333 (Status [200 OK]):
>   App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus

Comment: No idea but you might be able to get the response code with `$response->getResponseStatus()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log you see in the worker's log file is outputted by Laravel and and it is not configurable.

Your best option is to define a custom log channel which logs to the worker's file and push your after your `HTTP` request.

1. Define a single file or path based logger channel *config/logging.php*:

   ```
   'supervisorLog' => [
       'driver' => 'single',
       'name' => 'supervisor-log',
       // ath should be same as stdout_logfile in supervisord.conf
       'path' => storage_path('path/to/supervisor/log/file'), 
       'locking' => false
   ],
   ```
2. Add this after `$result = json_decode($response->getBody());` in your `ApiUpdateItemJob.php`:

   `Log::channel('supervisorLog')->info("Processing item id " + $this->item_id +" (Status ["+ $response->status() +"]): App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus");`

The result will be something like:

> [2019-12-17 05:11:53][40792760] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
>
> [2019-12-17 05:11:54][40792761] Processing item id #333333 (Status [200]): App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus
>
> [2019-12-17 05:11:54][40792760] Processed: App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor will output anything written to stdout to a log file as defined on [it's config file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration):

```
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

So you can write to `php://stdout` on `handle` method of your job to be written on Supervisor workers' log:

```php
public function handle()
{
    fwrite(STDOUT, "Processing item id #{$this->item_id} (Status [{$this->status}]): App\\Jobs\\UpdateItemStatus");

    //$data = [
    //    'id' => $this->item_id,
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new channel to `config/logging.php`:

```
'updateItem' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/updateItem.log'),
    'level' => 'info',
]
```

Then log whatever you want inside the `handle` of your `UpdateItemJob`:

```
Log::channel('updateItem')->info('Hello world!!');
```

Then view your log file live. For example:

```
tail -f storage/logs/updateItem.log
```

If you don't want a custom log file. just use `Log::info('Hello world!!');` and `tail` the default log file in `storage/logs`

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can modify it so that it logs to your regular logs, then you dont need to care about creating a new supervisor log just for queue worker, it will use you configured logging output inside logging.php

```
use App\Classes\Extensions\Queue\CustomWorkCommand;
class ArtisanServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->extend('command.queue.work', function ($command, $app) {
            return new CustomWorkCommand($app['queue.worker']);
        });
    }
}
```

Create a new class inside app/Classes/Extensions/Queue, or anywhere you like, and override writeStatus command:

```
namespace App\Classes\Extensions\Queue;

use Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand as ConsoleWorkCommand;

class WorkCommand extends ConsoleWorkCommand {

    protected function writeStatus(Job $job, $status, $type)
    {
        if($type == "comment"){
            $type = "info";
        }
        $output = sprintf("[%s][%s] %s %s",
            Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            $job->getJobId(),
            str_pad("{$status}:", 11), 
            $job->resolveName()
        );
        Log::$type($output);
    }
}
```

Add this line to app.php

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `displayName` method within your job to customize what is logs:

```
public function displayName()
{
    return "item id #{$this->item_id} (Status [{$this->status}]): App\Jobs\UpdateItemStatus";
}
```

PD: I know the answer its too late, but I arrived to this question looking for the same and I found this answer elsewhere